# How Do I Restrict List Of Network Terminals To Access My Vb.Net Application

Tags: vb.net, networking, terminal

I have designed a vb.net windows application now I would like to give security to my application such as Multi user license.

For example if a user haves only 5 user license than he should be run the application only in 1 server + 4 network machine. When the 6th network machine use the application it should prompt user that "You have only 5 user license".

I need the list of network machine accessing the server application so that i can restrict network terminals.

Any idea how should i proceed it ?

Kindly assist on this.

Thanks.

Comment: This could get closed for being too broad.  As a starting point, you'll want to create some repository containing the installed client base tied to each license.  Is it concurrent or total installs?  This will determine where the application 'calls home' to your repository to see if the application can run/be installed.

Comment: It is concurrent installs.